# How to get data in GUI's Main window from a child window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn Python and trying to built up a GUI. I am facing a problem which is as follows:

In my Code I am trying to get the inputs from a user when 'Ausgewahlte' Check box is selected, which upon selection open up the child window and allow the user to enter the data. Now I have to tell in the main GUI to take the data either from the Child window or use the default data as per the selection between 'Alle' or 'Ausgewahlte'.

Firstly, I am not able to use the data defined in Child window in a main GUI.

It will be great if anyone among you will be able to help.

Thanking you in anticipation !!!

Regards

`

```
import Tkinter
import tkSimpleDialog

class PST_TEG(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):

        # Label
         self.grid()
         label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Projekt Root Ordner Name :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
         label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Projekt Name :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
         label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Experiment Name :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=2,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')        
         label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Plattform Name :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=3,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
         label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Anzahl der Szenarien :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
         label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Temperatur Kuhlwasser :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=5,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
         label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Szenarien :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=6,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')

        # Entry 

         self.entry1=Tkinter.Entry(self)
         self.entry1.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW',pady=5)
         self.entry2=Tkinter.Entry(self)
         self.entry2.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='EW',pady=5)
         self.entry3=Tkinter.Entry(self)
         self.entry3.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='EW',pady=5)
         self.entry4=Tkinter.Entry(self)
         self.entry4.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky='EW',pady=5)
         self.entry5=Tkinter.Entry(self)
         self.entry5.grid(column=1,row=4,sticky='EW',pady=5)
         self.entry6=Tkinter.Entry(self)
         self.entry6.grid(column=1,row=5,sticky='EW',pady=5)


        # Checkbutton
         global CheckVar1
         global CheckVar2
         global Checkbutton1
         global Checkbutton2
         CheckVar1= Tkinter.IntVar()
         CheckVar2=Tkinter.IntVar()
         Checkbutton1=Tkinter.Checkbutton(self, text="Alle Szenarien",variable=CheckVar1,command=self.alle).grid(column=1,row=6,pady=10,sticky='W')
         Checkbutton2=Tkinter.Checkbutton(self, text="Ausgewählte",variable=CheckVar2,command=self.selected).grid(column=1,row=6,padx=110,sticky='W')

        # Button

         button1 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Übernehmen",command=self.Uebernehmen)
         button1.grid(column=1,row=8,pady=10,columnspan=1,sticky='W')
         button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Reset",command=self.clear_fields)
         button2.grid(column=1,row=8,pady=10,padx=90,sticky='W')

    def OnButtonClick(self):

        global Anzahl_Szenarien1
        global Anfang_Temperatur1
        global Szenario_all
        global Szenario_all1
        global Szenario_selected
        global ProjectRoot1
        global ProjectName1
        global ExperimentName1
        global PlatformName1

        ProjectRoot1=self.entry1.get()
        ProjectName1=self.entry2.get()
        ExperimentName1=self.entry3.get()
        PlatformName1= self.entry4.get()
        Anzahl_Szenarien1 = int(self.entry5.get())
        Anfang_Temperatur1 = int(self.entry6.get())

        print 'Projekt ordner: %s' % ProjectRoot1
        print 'Projekt Name: %s' % ProjectName1
        print 'Experiment Name: %s' % ExperimentName1
        print 'Platform Name: %s' % PlatformName1
        print 'Anzahl Szenarien: %d' % Anzahl_Szenarien1
        print 'Temperatur Kuhlwasser: %d' % Anfang_Temperatur1




    def clear_fields(self):

        self.entry1.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry2.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry3.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry4.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry5.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry6.delete(0, 'end')

        if(CheckVar1.get()):
           CheckVar1.set(0)

        if(CheckVar2.get()):
           CheckVar2.set(0)

    def new_data(self,data):
        Szenario_all=data
        self.OnButtonClick()
        print Szenario_all

    def alle(self):


         self.OnButtonClick()
         all=Anzahl_Szenarien1
         all=all+1
         Szenario_all=list(range(1,all))
         print Szenario_all

    def selected(self):

        child_window(self.parent)         

    def Uebernehmen(self):

        master.destroy()

class child_window(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.root = Tkinter.Toplevel(parent)
        label = Tkinter.Label(self.root,text="Bitte geben Sie die Szenarien nummer ein :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
        self.root.entry1=Tkinter.Entry(self.root)
        self.root.entry1.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='EW',padx=10)

        self.ok_button = Tkinter.Button(self.root,text=u"OK",command=self.closechild).grid(column=1,row=2,pady=10,columnspan=1,sticky='W')


    def closechild(self):

        Szenario_all1= self.root.entry1.get()
        self.parent.new_data(Szenario_all1) 

        self.root.destroy()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    master = PST_TEG(None)
    master.title('PST TEG')
    w = 400
    h = 275 
    ws = master.winfo_screenwidth() 
    hs = master.winfo_screenheight() 
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    master.mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example to modify parent Window from child window.

In `selected()` method pass `self` argument which will be the parent of child window.

```
def selected(self):
    child_window(self)
```

You can change child_window as following:

```
class child_window(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self,parent):

        #Save parent reference

        self.parent = parent
        self.root = Tkinter.Toplevel(parent)
        label = Tkinter.Label(self.root,text="Bitte geben Sie die Szenarien nummer ein :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')

        #Create your widget as this, simple to read.

        self.entry1 = Tkinter.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry1.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='EW',padx=10)

        self.ok_button = Tkinter.Button(self.root,text=u"OK",command=self.closechild).grid(column=1,row=2,pady=10,columnspan=1,sticky='W')


    def closechild(self):

        Szenario_all1= self.entry1.get()

        #self.parent.new_data(Szenario_all1)

        #To change parent value of entry1 from here
        #just call insert() method.

        self.parent.entry1.insert(0, Szenario_all1)

        #To delete content of self.parent.entry1 use:
        #self.parent.entry1.delete(0, len(self.parent.entry1.get()))

        self.root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right...
For this kind of input (string I suppose) you can use

```
tkSimpleDialog.askstring(title, prompt [,options])
```

To create a dialog. This function returns string entered.

Comment: Hello....Thanks for the reply. You are right that I can use the SimpleDialog but I don't want the cancel button and that's why I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use another entry for the "Ausgewahlte" option. Initially you can set that entry to disabled, so that no text could be entered.

```
self.entry7=Tkinter.Entry(self, state = 'disabled')
```

When the "Ausgewahlte" check-box is selected you can then enable the entry allowing the user to enter his/her text.

```
self.entry7['state'] = 'normal'
```

Also I would avoid using global variables, you could just add them to the class like this:

```
self.variableName = ...
```

So in the end I would do something like this:

```
import Tkinter
import tkSimpleDialog

class PST_TEG(Tkinter.Tk):

def __init__(self,parent):
    Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.initialize()

def initialize(self):

    # Label
    self.grid()
    label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Projekt Root Ordner Name :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
    label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Projekt Name :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
    label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Experiment Name :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=2,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')        
    label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Plattform Name :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=3,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
    label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Anzahl der Szenarien :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
    label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Temperatur Kuhlwasser :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=5,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')

    label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Ausgewahlte :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=6,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')

    label = Tkinter.Label(self,text="Szenarien :",anchor="w").grid(column=0,row=7,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
    # Entry 

    self.entry1=Tkinter.Entry(self)
    self.entry1.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW',pady=5)
    self.entry2=Tkinter.Entry(self)
    self.entry2.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='EW',pady=5)
    self.entry3=Tkinter.Entry(self)
    self.entry3.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='EW',pady=5)
    self.entry4=Tkinter.Entry(self)
    self.entry4.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky='EW',pady=5)
    self.entry5=Tkinter.Entry(self)
    self.entry5.grid(column=1,row=4,sticky='EW',pady=5)
    self.entry6=Tkinter.Entry(self)
    self.entry6.grid(column=1,row=5,sticky='EW',pady=5)
    self.entry7=Tkinter.Entry(self, state = 'disabled')
    self.entry7.grid(column=1,row=6,sticky='EW',pady=5)


    # Checkbutton
    self.CheckVar1= Tkinter.IntVar()
    self.CheckVar2=Tkinter.IntVar()
    self.Checkbutton1=Tkinter.Checkbutton(self, text="Alle Szenarien",variable=self.CheckVar1,command=self.alle).grid(column=1,row=7,pady=10,sticky='W')
    self.Checkbutton2=Tkinter.Checkbutton(self, text="Ausgewahlte",variable=self.CheckVar2,command=self.selected).grid(column=1,row=7,padx=110,sticky='W')
    # Button

    button1 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Ubernehmen",command=self.Uebernehmen)
    button1.grid(column=1,row=10,pady=10,columnspan=1,sticky='W')
    button2 = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Reset",command=self.clear_fields)
    button2.grid(column=1,row=10,pady=10,padx=90,sticky='W')

def OnButtonClick(self):

    self.ProjectRoot1=self.entry1.get()
    self.ProjectName1=self.entry2.get()
    self.ExperimentName1=self.entry3.get()
    self.PlatformName1= self.entry4.get()
    self.Anzahl_Szenarien1 = int(self.entry5.get())
    self.Anfang_Temperatur1 = int(self.entry6.get())

    print 'Projekt ordner: %s' % self.ProjectRoot1
    print 'Projekt Name: %s' % self.ProjectName1
    print 'Experiment Name: %s' % self.ExperimentName1
    print 'Platform Name: %s' % self.PlatformName1
    print 'Anzahl Szenarien: %d' % self.Anzahl_Szenarien1
    print 'Temperatur Kuhlwasser: %d' % self.Anfang_Temperatur1


def clear_fields(self):

    self.entry1.delete(0, 'end')
    self.entry2.delete(0, 'end')
    self.entry3.delete(0, 'end')
    self.entry4.delete(0, 'end')
    self.entry5.delete(0, 'end')
    self.entry6.delete(0, 'end')
    self.entry7.delete(0, 'end')
    self.entry7['state'] = 'disabled'

    if(self.CheckVar1.get()):
       self.CheckVar1.set(0)

    if(self.CheckVar2.get()):
       self.CheckVar2.set(0)

def new_data(self,data):
    self.Szenario_all = data
    self.OnButtonClick()
    print Szenario_all

def alle(self):
    self.OnButtonClick()
    all = self.Anzahl_Szenarien1
    all = all+1
    Szenario_all = list(range(1,all))
    print Szenario_all

def selected(self):
    self.entry7['state'] = 'normal' 

def Uebernehmen(self):
    master.destroy()



if __name__ == "__main__":

master = PST_TEG(None)
master.title('PST TEG')
w = 400
h = 290 
ws = master.winfo_screenwidth() 
hs = master.winfo_screenheight() 
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even I did not want to use global variables but I am using global as I will be Importing this GUI in another script and the variables defined in GUI will be used in that other script. This has worked but It would be great if you can suggest another way apart from using global.

Comment: What I usually do to avoid globals is to create a file (let's call it "sharedVar.py") where I declare all the variables that will be shared among different modules. Each module will just import that file and use the variables that have been declared there.